# Setting colors for CGContextRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I was just wondering how does `setStroke` know to set the stroke for `context` when `context` isn't mentioned at all in the `setStroke` method?

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);
[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:0.6 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0] setStroke];
```

Btw how often do you programmatically draw your own objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the implementation of `setStroke` for your color:

```
- (void)setStroke {
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.CGColor);
}
```

It uses the same function to get the context that you're using.

Comment: Considering UIKit is closed source, and unless you work for Apple or have really good friends who don't care much for their job over there, there is no way to know for sure that that is the implementation :) Now while it is the simplest way we can't be too sure based on some of the code examples I've seen on the developer site.

Comment: @Joe I disassembled the iOS Simulator's `UIKit` binary using [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/).  I'm very sure that's how it's implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you retrieved the context to set the line width is the same way the color can set the stroke. The reason is because there is only one current graphics context for the main thread retrieved by [`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html). You can push and pop different contexts but that function will always return the current one. Just remember that in iOS this function is not thread safe and should only be called from the main thread.